# Volume of rotation $y=x^3$ ; lines $x=0$ ; $y=8$ ; about $x=2$?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume, rotations

I'm having trouble with this problem, I'm not sure how to proceed. I know if we were to rotate about the $y$-axis ($x=0$), then I would have the following disk method.

$$\pi \int_0^8 y^{2/3}dy = \frac{(96\pi)}{5}$$

In my case, it becomes a washer method, but I'm unable to properly setup the formula to calculate.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Thank you Nosrati for the edit. I couldn't figure out the proper formatting.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the cylindrical shell method:

[image: Solid of revolution]

$$ V=\int_0^22\pi rh\,dx$$

where $r=2-x$ and $h=8-x^3$.

Using the annulus or "disk/washer" method:

[image: Disk/washer method]

$$ V=\int_0^8 \pi(R^2-r^2)\,dy$$

where $R=2$ and $r=2-y^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: Since we avoided the shell method in my classes, sticking to the washer method, the formula you gave me here seems to differ from the one given in the previous comment. With your formula I would obtain (96pi)/5, which is the same as if we rotated around the x-axis (x=0).

Comment: I also included the disk/washer method, which is the second formula. You always begin with the basic formula then study the graph to determine how to express $R$ and $r$ in terms of the variable.

Comment: In the disk/washer method you always take a slice through the region perpendicular to the axis of rotation. When you extend that slice it will cross either the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis. Whichever axis it crosses, that is the variable you must use. In this case, a slice perpendicular to $x=2$ crosses the $y$-axis, so one must integrate with respect to $y$ and find $R$ and $r$ as functions of $y$. But in this case, $R$ happens to have a constant value of $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. In this case would the volume be (96pi)/5 , making it identical to a rotation about the y-axis ?

Comment: No, it would not be identical to a rotation about the $y$-axis, since that would produce an entirely different solid. So one would not expect the volume of that solid to be the same. Both integrals which I presented are elementary integrals and you should be able to solve them and get the same result for both.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I believe to have made a very basic mistake in my integration on top of having trouble visualizing the solid. Thank you again for your help in clearing this up for me.

Comment: Two useful tools to help with visualization are the free software Geogebra and the free online graphing tool at desmos.com. I created the graphs at desmos.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81886/discussion-between-john-wayland-bales-and-ajgk).

Answer (score 1):

In these types of problems, the best way to start is to make a sketch of the function. This looks almost like a parabola from $(0,0)$ to $(2,8)$ that you rotate around a vertical line at $x=2$. It's a series of disks, with smaller and smaller radius as $y$ increases, with the largest disk at $y=0$. If you look at the picture, observe the lines $x=0$, $y=x^3$, and $x=2$. It should be obvious that the radius that you care about is is $2-x=2-y^\frac{1}{3}$. You should now be able to finish the problem.

Comment: I had sketched the graph, I just wasn't sure of which values to use for the radius, and if there was an inner and outer function (R^2 - r^2). I came to the answer of (16pi)/5.

I just have another question, mostly to help me with my intuition with these problems. I'm just wondering why the volume is different for rotating about x=2, rather than the x-axis. From my graph it seems the same surface area is being rotated, hence I would expect an identical Volume, could you help me understand why the volumes are different despite the same surface being rotated?

Comment: It's the same line, not the same surface. If $y$ is the vertical axis, and $x$ and $z$ form the horizontal plane, try to plot what your figure would look in the $xz$ plane. In 3D, rotating around the $x=0$ axis looks like the inside of a champagne flute, while the other one looks like a cone where you keep shaving from the sides, while keeping the base and height constant

Comment: I'm not sure if I misunderstood what you wrote.. To be sure, in the formula, would the R = 2 & r = 2 - y^(1/3) ?

Comment: That is correct.